# Подведение промежуточных итогов по нескольким группам

Tags: sql, oracle19c

Доброго времени суток всем!

Есть набор данных, по которому считаются агрегированные значения.

Пример агрегации:

| № | Филиал | Продажи |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3 |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 3 | **Total A + B** | **5** |
| 4 | C | 1 |
| 5 | D | 3 |
| 6 | **Total C + D** | **4** |
| 7 | E | 2 |
| 8 | F | 3 |
| 9 | **Total E + F** | **5** |
| 10 | **Total C + D + E + F** | **9** |
| 11 | **Total A + B + C + D + E + F** | **14** |

Результаты считаются с помощью `CTE`, из которой через `union` подводятся промежуточные итоги.

Вопрос:
Как просчитывать промежуточные результаты в строках 3, 6, 9, 10, 11 без использования `union` в `select`?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

1. агрегировать и разделить по филиалам в PIVOT
2. там же сразу собрать промежуточные итоги
3. перевернуть таблицу обратно UNPIVOT

Простой пример:

```
-- автор не указал исходную структуру таблицы
CREATE TABLE testTable (
  BranchID VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
);

-- предположу что идет одна запись на продажу
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('A');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('B');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('C');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('D');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('D');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('D');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('E');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('E');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('F');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('F');
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES ('F');

-- выборка
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1) AS "№",
  u.testCol AS "Филиал",
  u.value AS "Продажи"
FROM
  (
    -- промежуточные итоги
    SELECT
      p."'A'" AS "A",
      p."'B'" AS "B",
      p."'A'" + p."'B'" AS "A + B",
      p."'C'" AS "C",
      p."'D'" AS "D",
      p."'C'" + p."'D'" AS "C + D",
      p."'E'" AS "E",
      p."'F'" AS "F",
      p."'E'" + p."'F'" AS "E + F",
      p."'C'" + p."'D'" + p."'E'" + p."'F'" AS "C + D + E + F",
      p."'A'" + p."'B'" + p."'C'" + p."'D'" + p."'E'" + p."'F'" AS "A + B + C + D + E + F"
    FROM
      testTable
      -- переворачиваем
      PIVOT (
        -- количество продаж
        COUNT(BranchID) 
        -- отдельно по филиалам
        FOR BranchID 
        IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')
      ) p
  ) t
  -- убираем переворот
  UNPIVOT (
    VALUE
    FOR testCol
    IN (
      ("A") AS 'A',
      ("B") AS 'B',
      ("A + B") AS 'A + B',
      ("C") AS 'C',
      ("D") AS 'D',
      ("C + D") AS 'C + D',
      ("E") AS 'E',
      ("F") AS 'F',
      ("E + F") AS 'E + F',
      ("C + D + E + F") AS 'C + D + E + F',
      ("A + B + C + D + E + F") AS 'A + B + C + D + E + F'
    )
  ) u
```